# Dataset of radio stations live streaming URLs, collaboratively curated

Tags: data-request, audio, media

Many radios all over the world are streaming live over the Internet.
Each of them have one or several URLs. I am looking for a curated dataset of these streams.

Requirements:

- Name of the radio (ex: `ar:راديو هلا: هلا أخبار , en:Radio Hala`)
- URL(s) of the stream (ex: `http://mp3hdfm32.hala.jo:8132`)
- (Optional) Bandwidth(s) (ex: `128kbps`)
- (Optional) [Genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_format) (ex: `All-news`)
- (Optional) Official website (ex: `http://www.hala.jo`)
- (Optional) Place where the radio's main studio is (ex: `31.962021, 35.940223`)
- (Optional) URL to the logo of the radio (ex: `http://www.hala.jo/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/hala-logo-retina.png`)

Notes:

- Bonus for any further curated data like wiki description or even aggregated ratings.
- The database must be reusable.
- Both established brick-and-airwaves radios and Internet-only radios are welcome.

Comment: I take it things like shoutcast.com have overly restrictive licensing terms (although shoutcast's itself seems pretty open)?

Comment: @BarryCarter: Shoutcast license says "*nonexclusive, nontransferable, non-sublicensable, revocable*" which is the opposite of open, unfortunately.

Comment: Streeamfinder is another commericial API option http://www.streamfinder.com/internet-radio-api/

Answer (score 5):

The site [**radio-browser.info**](http://www.radio-browser.info/) might be what you look for. It is a community-curated, public domain dedicated collection of radio streams from all over the world. As of July 2016, it contains just over 4700 stations.

[image: radio-browser.info station list]

For each stream, it offers the fields:

> - name
> - stream URL
> - stream type (codec, bitratea)
> - station homepage URL
> - country, state
> - language
> - favicon, image
> - arbitrary number of tags (musical genres, or news, ...)

This data is accessible through

- a [webpage GUI](http://www.radio-browser.info/gui/) for exploring the database,
- [daily dumps](http://www.radio-browser.info/backups/) of its MariaDB,
- a documented web [API](http://www.radio-browser.info/webservice) that delivers JSON or XML for HTTP requests, or
- several plugins or mobile apps that use the API.
  I found out about this site through the Android app [RadioDroid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.programmierecke.radiodroid2).

Answer (score 3):

There is a (short) list of [Creative-Commons friendly Internet Radio Stations](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Internet_Radio). This meets your license criteria but not the global scope you are probably hoping for. In this list you have a short meta-data description and also URLs. Like all things open and wiki, this list can and should be expanded by the community.

```
Name: The Radio CC
Language: German/Deutsch 
Main URL: http://www.the-radio.cc
Radio URL: http://s.the-radio.cc
Content Directory: http://wiki.creativecommons.org/The_Radio_CC
```